# Simple classical mechanics problem to compute minimum distance attained between two ships moving with constant velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, calculus, relative-motion

I have been reading the book "A Course in Classical Physics 1 - Mechanics" by Alessandro Bettini.  I have reached a problem in the first chapter that I am having trouble with.

The problem statement goes :

> We are on a ship travelling at 10 kn heading east. We see another ship, which we know moves at 20 kn to North, 6 miles distant
> in the South direction. What is the minimum distance the two ships will be (without changing their courses)? After how much time ?
> On the sea distances are measured in nautical miles and velocities in knots (1 kn = 1 mile/h). Assume
> for the mile the round figure of 1800 m.

The answer key for the problem states :

> She will cross at 3 miles towards stern in 18′

This is not the answer that I am getting and wanted some help to see what I could be doing wrong. My solution so far is below.

$\require{amsmath}$
$\require{cases}$
$\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}$

We can draw the scenario :

[image]

Here ship A is my ship and ship B is the other ship. We work in a frame attached to
ship A with the positive y axis pointing North and the positive x axis pointing East. Let $\vec r_{A}(t)$ be the position of ship A as a function of time $t$ and $\vec r_{B}(t)$ be the position of ship B.
Let $\vec v_{A}(t)$ and $\vec v_{B}(t)$ be the velocities of the two ships. The velocity functions have units of knots (miles per hour) and the position functions have units of miles. $t$ has units of hours.

We have :
\begin{align}
\vec v_{A}(t) & = (0,0) \\\\
\vec v_{B}(t) & = (-10,20) 
\end{align}
So :
\begin{align}
\vec r_{A}(t) & = (0,0)\\\\
\vec r_{B}(t) & = (-10t,20t-6)
\end{align}
and the displacement vector between the two ships is :
\begin{equation}
\vec r_{AB}(t) = \vec r_{B}(t) - \vec r_{A}(t) = (-10t,20t - 6) = \vec r_{B}(t)
\end{equation}
So the distance between the two ships is given by :
\begin{align}
d_{AB}(t) = |\vec r_{AB}(t)| 
  & = \sqrt{(-10t)^{2} + (20t-6)^{2}}\\\\
  & = \sqrt{100t^{2} + (20t - 6)^{2}}
\end{align}
We see :
\begin{align}
(20t - 6)^{2} 
  & = (20t - 6)(20t - 6)\\\\
  & = 400t^{2} - 120t - 120t + 36 \\\\
  & = 400t^{2} - 240t + 36
\end{align}
So :
\begin{align}
d_{AB}(t) 
  & = \sqrt{100t^{2} + 400t^{2} - 240t + 36}\\\\
  & = \sqrt{500t^{2} - 240t + 36}\\\\
  & = \sqrt{f(t)}
\end{align}
Where :
\begin{equation}
f(t) = 500t^{2} - 240t + 36
\end{equation}
It seems :
\begin{equation}
\hat t = \argmin_{t \geq 0} d_{AB}(t) \Leftrightarrow \hat t = \argmin_{t \geq 0} f(t)
\end{equation}
as the square root function is increasing. We see :
\begin{equation}
f'(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\left( 500t^{2} - 240t + 36 \right) = 1000t - 240
\end{equation}
and :
\begin{align}
f'(t) = 0 
  & \Leftrightarrow 1000t - 240 = 0 \\\\
  & \Leftrightarrow 1000t = 240 \\\\
  & \Leftrightarrow t = \frac{240}{1000} \\\\
  & \Leftrightarrow t = \frac{24}{100} \\\\
  & \Leftrightarrow t = \frac{6}{25}
\end{align}
So :
\begin{align}
f'(t) > 0 \text{ when }  t > \frac{6}{25} \\\\
f'(t) \leq 0 \text{ when }  t \leq \frac{6}{25}
\end{align}
So $f(t)$ is monotone decreasing before $t = \frac{6}{25}$ and increasing
afterwards. This means the minimum of $f(t)$ is at $t = \frac{6}{25}$.
So :
\begin{equation}
\argmin_{t \geq 0} d_{AB}(t) = \frac{6}{25} \text{ hours }
\end{equation}
And we see :
\begin{align}
\frac{6}{25} \text{ hours } 
  & = \left[ \frac{6}{25} \cdot 60 \right] \text{ minutes }\\\\
  & = \frac{360}{25} \text{ minutes }\\\\ 
  & = 14.4 \text{ minutes } 
\end{align}
Which is not equal to the correct answer of 18 minutes.

Can someone show me where I am going wrong ?

Comment: You differentiated the wrong function. You need to differentiate $\sqrt f(x)$, not f(x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution looks fine, textbooks (and answers to problems therein) do have mistakes.

The answer seems to state that $B$ passes directly behind (i.e. to the West of) $A$ after $18$ minutes, when the separation of the ships is 3 miles. This is correct, but this is not when the distance between the ships is minimum, and hence not what the question is asking.